# Get only one item with specific field value

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

How to distinct result by specific field value. For example i have `group_id` field and i don't want to get multiple results with same group_id.

```
[{"name": "Eva", "group_id": "female"}, 
 {"name": "Marina", "group_id": "female"},
 {"name": "Raf", "group_id": "male"},
 {"name": "Manvel", "group_id": "male"}]
```

For example this is my documents list. From this list i need to get only one male and one female. So i think i need to group by field "group" and get only one from match that group. I think this is something simple, and i don't need to write that match. In docs probably example is for more complex cases.

[image]

Comment: Ok. And what is your query that doesn't work?

Comment: {
 'aggs': {
    'group_by_state': {
      'terms': {
        'field': 'group'
      },
      'size': 1
    }
  }
}

Comment: Don't use `size: 1`. Remove that and add the `top_hits` with size: 1. I've updated the sample query where I made much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Use `top_hits` aggregation as a sub-aggregation for your `terms` aggregation. An example you can find in the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_example

```
POST /sales/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs": {
        "top_tags": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "group_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_one": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about this documentation but it's not enough clear for me, and i tried what you just wrote here, it's not working. But thanks for your respond.

Comment: Your original post is not enough clear for me either. So, please update your post and specifically mention what you tried and what exactly doesn't work ;-).

Comment: this is not working either. do i need to change 'top_tags' field or 'top_one'?
my actual field name is 'group_id' so i think that's correct. but i can't understand the rest under 'aggs' field.

Comment: `top_tags` shouldn't use `size` at all, and `top_one` should have `"size": 1`.

Comment: yes i did exactly as you described. just updated post to include image.

Comment: I'm not getting error, seems it's not working as i expected. I have another result in aggs. So what i need to do is get result from aggs instead of hits?
Or maybe i need to remove actual hits with aggs? beside of this aggs i have another small query structure that needs to be matched.

Comment: The results will be in aggs, yes.

Comment: Ok then seems this is the answer if there is no other option to filter documents with same group_id and get only one?

Comment: Grouping is with aggregations. If you want to filter some groups, then you can also add a query, but grouping is only about aggregations.

Comment: Yes probably question is not described well. What i need to do is to get result with specific field only once per request.